# Delete Content Using Variable in Range Function

Tags: vba, excel, range

> Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I am getting above error as soon as I execute below sequence. My objective here is to delete content of all cells falling in range of current cell till C200.

```
Posit2.Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(53, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Address      ' $C$52 is output
Range(ActiveCell.Address, c200).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line is wrong,

`Range(ActiveCell.Address & " : C200").ClearContents`

Is right

Answer (score 0):

You can also try replacing your error line to:

```
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(200, "C")).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you will want to move away from selecting.  Assuming Posit2 is a reference to C52 on Sheet1 in your example then

```
Dim Posit2 as Range

set Posit2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("C52")

With Posit2.parent
  .Range(Posit2, .Cells(200,"C")).ClearContents
End With
```

First two lines are for illustration as you should already have code that does that.  Also, by referencing the sheet, Sheet1 would not need to be the activesheet.